# python xlwings package error: OSError: [WinError -2147467259] Unspecified error

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, xlwings

I'm trying to write Python data-frame to `.xlsm` file using xlwings package. My code works fine sometimes, but sometimes it fails and throws:

`OSError: [WinError -2147467259] Unspecified error`

**Sample code:**

```
import xlwings as xw
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
app = xw.App(visible=False)
filename="test.xlsm"
book = xw.Book(filename)
sht = book.sheets("ASSET")
#asset_df ,asset_spec_df are the  data-frame (i get this data-frame value from another function)
sht.range('B9').options(index=False, header=False).value = asset_df
sht=book.sheets("ASSETSPEC")
sht.range('B9').options(index=False, header=False).value = asset_spec_df
book.save()
book.close()
app.quit()
```

This code works as it should sometimes, but sometimes throws an error below:

**Error:**

```
 book = xw.Book(filename) --- error line

  File "C:\Users\prabhaahar.nagesh\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\xlwings\main.py", line 514, in __init__
    for wb in app.books:
  File "C:\Users\prabhaahar.nagesh\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\xlwings\main.py", line 368, in books
    return Books(impl=self.impl.books)
  File "C:\Users\prabhaahar.nagesh\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\xlwings\_xlwindows.py", line 392, in books
    return Books(xl=self.xl.Workbooks)
  File "C:\Users\prabhaahar.nagesh\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\xlwings\_xlwindows.py", line 313, in xl
    self._xl = get_xl_app_from_hwnd(self._hwnd)
  File "C:\Users\prabhaahar.nagesh\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\xlwings\_xlwindows.py", line 223, in get_xl_app_from_hwnd
    ptr = accessible_object_from_window(child_hwnd)
  File "C:\Users\prabhaahar.nagesh\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\xlwings\_xlwindows.py", line 191, in accessible_object_from_window
    res = oledll.oleacc.AccessibleObjectFromWindow(
  File "_ctypes/callproc.c", line 948, in GetResult
OSError: [WinError -2147467259] Unspecified error
```

Comment: If the same book (aka. `.xlsm`) is opened in multiple instances, the application will throw an error.

Answer (score 0):

As written in the comment the application will throw an error if the same Book (aka. `.xlsm`) is opened in several instances at a time.

Check if this application that you try to run now is already running somewhere in the background. If so, kill these active applications and run again.

Here is more information about the issue -> [link](https://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/connect_to_workbook.html)

Comment: Before running that code i have closed all the opened .xlsm Excel instance from task manager and the problem still exists.

Comment: Not `.xlsm` but the python programs running in the background that use .xlsm to read data. If you restart your computer and right after you run the above python program it will work without a problem.